# Where to go now?

Tags: candy-box-2

I have got the world map and the stone axe. What do I do now? There is no box that says "Let's go" as in the next quest. Or where should the button be and how do you get it?

Comment: Where were you last? What have you done so far?

Comment: Have you actually seen the map? When I first got the map, it took me a while to actually *see* it because I didn’t notice the top of the screen and kept wandering around the village trying to figure out how to get out .

Answer (score 1):

The world map in Candy Box 2 is interactive. In order to proceed to a new area (or quest, for that matter), **click on different parts of the map**.

In your case, the next main quest is the **desert** - but who knows? There might be secrets to find, too.